# Programmatically open an N level self nested mat-menu component with matMenuTrigger openMenu

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to make a self nested component that uses Angular Material mat-menu. I have a flyoutcomponent that is a wrapper for flyout-menu-item component, that will have a button as a matMenuTrigger for the nested component that will appear as many levels as the FeatureInput.FeatureChoices dictates. FeatureInput is an object that has FeatureChoices that may or may not contain other featurechoices etc N levels deep. Below code does not compile but it should demonstrate what I am doing. Basically I have flyout menu component as a input to a form and I am trying to load a stored answer on a form rather than select new, which I can do easily using the nested component. The desired behavior is that if the user clicks top matMenuTrigger button to open the top menu that it would expand all child menus to the menu item that matches with the `FeatureInput.FeatureValue` and sets the menu item _highlighted to true. I am using the menuOpen input parameter  and ngChanges successfully to find the match(with I a setTimeout which cannot be right). Basically when I console.log this.trigger it is undefined. Ideally in the ngOnChange to the openMenu I would go through all menus and call openMenu on all the triggers but I cannot get access to the matMenuTrigger with ViewChild as the docs say. I get undefined. *-( All help welcome please and thanks.

Here is flyout template component.

```
<div>
    <buttonmat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu" 
                                            (onMenuOpen)="onMenuOpen()" 
                                            (onMenuClose)="onMenuClose()">
      <span [innerHTML]="featureInput.Text"></span>
    </button>
    <app-flyout-menu-item #menu 
       [featureChoicesObject]="featureInput.FeatureChoices"></app-flyout-menu-item>
  </div>
```

And here is its .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-flyout',
  templateUrl: './flyout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flyout.component.scss']
})
export class FlyoutComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() featureInput: FeatureInput

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onMenuOpen() {
    this.menuOpen = true;
  }

  onMenuClose() {
    this.menuOpen = false;
  }
}
```

And here is flyout-menu-item template

```
<mat-menu #childMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
    <span *ngFor="let featureChoice of featureChoices">
      <span>
        <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu">
          <span [innerHTML]="featureChoice.Text"></span>
        </button>
        <app-flyout-menu-item #menu 
                            [menuOpen]="menuOpen"
                            [featureInput]="featureInput" 
                            [featureChoicesObject]="featureChoice.FeatureChoices"
          (onOptionSelected)="someService.SomeMethod($event)"></app-flyout-menu-item>
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="!featureChoice.FeatureChoices">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="selectOption(featureChoice.ID)" [innerHTML]="featureChoice.Text" value="{{featureChoice.ID}}"></button>
      </span>
    </span>
  </mat-menu>
```

And here is its .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, ViewChild, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material';


import { FeatureChoice } from 'app/model/feature-choice';
import { FeatureInput } from 'app/model/feature-input';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flyout-menu-item',
  templateUrl: './flyout-menu-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flyout-menu-item.component.scss']
})
export class FlyoutMenuItemComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('menu') public menu;
  @ViewChild('childMenu') public childMenu;
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) public trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  @Input() featureInput: FeatureInput;

  @Input() featureChoicesObject: FeatureChoice;
  @Output() onOptionSelected: EventEmitter<FeatureInput> = new EventEmitter<FeatureInput>();

  constructor(public solutionDataService: SolutionDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.trigger);
  }

ngOnChanges(simpleChanges: SimpleChanges) {

    if (simpleChanges.menuOpen && simpleChanges.menuOpen.currentValue) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // console.log(this.menu);
        const itemsArray = this.childMenu.items.toArray();
        for (let x = 0; x < itemsArray.length; x++) {
          const menuItem = itemsArray[x];
          if (this.featureInput.FeatureValue !== '' && menuItem._elementRef.nativeElement.value === this.featureInput.FeatureValue) {
            menuItem._highlighted = true;
          }
        }
      }, 1);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Anyone out there working with nested mat-menu?

Answer (score 0):

`this.menuOpen = true;`

Perhaps add `menuOpen: boolean = false` as an attribute at the top of your FlyoutComponent. I don't know where the value  of menuOpen is saved.

Answer (score 0):

the menuOpen property relates to the matMenuTrigger.

here's an example:

```
<button [ngClass]="{'active-icon': trigger.menuOpen}" type="button" mat-
icon-button #trigger="matMenuTrigger"  [matMenuTriggerFor]="help">
    <mat-icon></mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #help="matMenu">
    <div> textId </div>
</mat-menu>
```